# Issue with the Bluetooth Pairing for BLE device in android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, pairing

I have to check the that BLE device is paired or not in Android - kotlin.

If the device is paired then only I have to move user to the particular screen.

So, The UI has list of scanned devices or we can say the list of previously added devices.
On tap of it I have to check the pairing status i.e. If it is paired then only I have to move to the next screen.

I have tried like this :

1. On click on row in list of devices, I am first trying to connect to that device.
2. It opens up the pairing dialog If not paired.
3. I have created a Broadcast receiver for it that checking the pairing status.

The condition I am checking is as below :

```
if (bleDeviceModel?.bleDevice?.bondState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
```

Here, I am getting **false** always.

Can you please guide better way to achieve such thing please ?

Comment: Are steps 1 and step 2 being successfully completed? In other words, before starting step 2, do you check that the device is connected? What are you using to verify that? And what is the code that you are using for pairing?

Comment: not done any code to check pairing. I am not using code for pairing but I can confirm that the device is successfully connected. In BleGattCallback, I am getting connect success flag.
I am checking pairing manually currently. As I am aware that its paired in my device.